# Where Firefox for Android is keeping add-on generated files?

Tags: root-access, file-system, firefox-for-android, browser-add-ons

I want to find a folder, where Firefox for Android is keeping files generated by installed add-ons (list of saved tabs in OneTab, for example).
I've tried to do a full root file system search (e.g. `onetab.html`, `store.json`) and looked insede specific app folders (e.g. `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox`). Found nothing but the `.xpi` extension files.

According to `Help` @ one-tab.com, tabs data is located in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\Profile Folder\jetpack\extension@one-tab.com\simple-storage\store.json` for a Windows desktop version. On Android, using rooted Amaze, I've found nothing similar.

Where should I search next? Are those files even visible for a root user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browse into the location `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/`. Among many directories there would be one directory whose name would end with `.default`. That is your Firefox profile directory. Within that directory, you can find what you are looking for. Extensions (xpi) are saved inside the `extensions` directory. Some extensions [may have data inside the directory](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/in-which-file-are-stored-an-add-on-settings-options/26064/2) `browsers-extension-data` while others may have it stored inside `storage/default`.

You can access those files by entering the URL `file:///data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/` in your Firefox browser. If you want to access them using a non-Firefox app, such as a file explorer app, than you need to have root access.

Comment: Thanks. In case of `OneTab`, found an `.sqlite` file with some `blob`s. Guess this could be a storage of a list of links. Investigating...