# Under what path is the data for Firefox extensions stored?

Tags: firefox-for-android

`/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox` is the directory in which Firefox's data is stored on Android. Where are Firefox's extensions' settings and data stored in there? The best I can tell is that they're going to be stored under `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/${profile}.default` since the names for everything outside of that folder appears to be for temporary files, the application's cache, and network-related things.

These are the paths that I'm sure do not contain extension data or that I'm sure do contain ALL of the extension data:

- `/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/${profile}.default/browser-extension-data`

Answer (score 2):

On Android 10, Firefox `68.7.0`

`/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/1q4ydoub.default/extensions`

I am not sure if the number before `.default` is specific to version or something else

For more details, see Firelord's answer here [Where Firefox for Android is keeping add-on generated files?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220691/131553)

Edit: You can paste `file:///data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/files/mozilla/1q4ydoub.default/extensions` in the search bar to see details of extensions, size, last modified time stamp